# How to set a method in Django rest framework's ViewSet to not require authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have [viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) like below :

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from paas.serializers import UserSerializer
import logging


logger=  logging.getLogger(__name__)

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self,request):
        pass

    def create(self,request):
        logger.info(request.data)
        current_user = UserSerializer.create()
```

Also, I use the DRF Token based authentication in my code. How can I simply say that this `create` method don't require authentications?
As you know after implementing authentication with the token, all request's should have `Token` in header's, and any request that doesn't have will get 403 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1067) on the DRF issues tracker, the best way seems to be to create a custom permissions class.  The view object has an `action` attribute that can be used to vary what you do in response to each sub-action for a ViewSet.

```
class IsCreationOrIsAuthenticated(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            if view.action == 'create':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

or the more detailed one from [AssembledAdam](https://github.com/assembledadam)

(Code copied here in line with SO policy of not just linking out, in case the link is broken or altered.)

```
class AnonCreateAndUpdateOwnerOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission:
        - allow anonymous POST
        - allow authenticated GET and PUT on *own* record
        - allow all actions for staff
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return view.action == 'create' or request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return view.action in ['retrieve', 'update', 'partial_update'] and obj.id == request.user.id or request.user.is_staff

class ListAdminOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow access to lists for admins
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return view.action != 'list' or request.user and request.user.is_staff
```